Acquire MSAL token in ASP.NET Core MVC site which is generated by Angular app for same app registered
We have two applications (one in Angular 14 and 2nd one is in ASP.NET Core MVC with C#), both are pointing to same app registered in Azure.
In Angular, Azure authentication is happening using the MSAL library, token is getting generated and getting stored in local storage.
We navigate to some pages of the ASP.NET Core MVC site from the Angular app. The problem is, we have to authenticate the user again in the ASP.NET Core MVC site, despite the user is already authenticated from Azure by the Angular site.
We want if user is already AD authenticated, then the same login should work for both the apps.
Can someone please provide any solution for this?

SSO? May I know whether user still need to login again when visiting Azure portal after sign in the Angular app? Per my understanding, if you already signed in with Angular app/Azure portal/MVC app, you don't need to sign in again in the same browser... I had a test before in an MVC app integrating Azure AD, if I signed in my MVC app, and I can visit Azure portal without login again in the same browser.

I download sample code here, the anuglar app worked as well as the MVC app, then no matter which app I signed in first, then when I open the website for the other app, it won't ask me to sign in again.
